# Phonegap Winodows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 viewport problems

Tags: css, cordova, windows-phone, viewport

I'm building an application with Phonegap on Windows Phone. 
In the css I've added

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}
```

which is fixing a problem with 720p and 1080p resolutions. 
When I started building, I noticed that on some of the emulators the viewport and scaling are perfect and on others is really bad, like the viewport doesn't work at all. The emulators are for Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1.

Does anybody know how to fix the viewport for the different OS?

---

Comment: Don't forget to actually formulate a question. It might be unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fix it by adding this to CordovaView.xaml.cs

```
string os = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
string result = Regex.Replace(os, "[A-Za-z ]", "");
return new Uri(AppRoot + "www/index.html#os=" + result, UriKind.Relative);
```

Instead of this:

```
return new Uri(AppRoot + "www/index.html", UriKind.Relative);
```

And then in my index.html I load different css file depending on os version:

```
try {
    var os = window.location.hash.slice(window.location.hash.indexOf('#') + 1).replace('os=', '').substr(0, 5);
    if (os == '8.0.1') {
        document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/windows_8.css" />');
    } else {
        document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/windows_8_1.css" />');
    }
} catch (e) {
    document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/windows_8_1.css" />');
}
```

windows_8.css:

```
@-ms-viewport {
   width: 480px;
   height: 800px;
}
```

windows_8_1.css:

```
@-ms-viewport {
   width: device-width;
}
```

I hope, that helps. It works for me.